# How to click on a image webpage using VBScript with no ID

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

need your help here.

I am trying to use vbs script to click on the this image with no element ID.

```
<img class="storeapp-icon ui-sortable-handle" alt="ABC" src="Resources/Icon/L0NpdHJpeC9YZW5BcHAvcmVzb3VyY2VzL3YyL2NqSlNOMEV6YzBoTVVsbFVPVlZvZUhWWU9GTlBRVkZZZGpOSlBRLS0vaW1hZ2U-?size=128" data-iconid="L0NpdHJpeC9YZW5BcHAvcmVzb3VyY2VzL3YyL2NqSlNOMEV6YzBoTVVsbFVPVlZvZUhWWU9GTlBRVkZZZGpOSlBRLS0vaW1hZ2U">
```

Tried using get element by name and ID and it would not work.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName("img")` to get all `<img>` elements.

If there are several such elements on the page, you can filter the list further, for instance by class using `getElementsByClassName("className")`.

```
Set nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("img") 
For Each element In nodeList
    ' Use the element stored in "element"
Next
```

With filtering by class name:

```
Set nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("img").getElementsByClassName("storeapp-icon")
Set element = nodeList(0)
' Use element
```